# code works but crashes in destructor (without copy constructor)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So, basically, I'm working on a homework and I have a linked list with polynomial coefficients and exponents. When copy c-tor is not included, code crashes when exiting main (destructor). With copy c-tor it doesn't happen, but I'm wondering why 'cause I haven't called copy c-tor anywhere explicitly. This is just a piece of the code. Coef function adds the node with parameters exp and coef in the list so I don't think it needs to be included.

```
CPList :: ~CPList ()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
        deleteFromHead();
}

void CPList :: deleteFromHead ()
{
    CPNode* tmp=head;
    if (head==tail)
        head=tail=NULL;
    else head=head->next;
    delete tmp;
}
CPList* CPList :: mul (CPList p1, CPList p2)
{
    CPList* res = new CPList;
    CPNode *first, *second;
    for (first=p1.head; first!=NULL; first=first->next)
        for (second=p2.head; second!=NULL; second=second->next)
            res->coef(first->exp+second->exp, first->coef*second->coef);
    res->check();
    return res;
}
```

It crashes just after this code, at the closed bracket.

```
int main ()
{
...
    ptr=p3.mul(p1, p2);
    ptr->printall();
}
```

It works normally when copy c-tor is included.

Comment: If you've no intention of calling a copy-ctor, or supporting it, then either delete it via C++11's syntax (`CPList(const CPList&) = delete;`) or declare it as `private:`. Doing so would have immediately shown you where this problem was rooted. Without a *valid* copy-ctor that honors the [Rule of Three/Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for a class with dynamic members, you're bound to hose yourself like this sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `p1` and `p2` are passed by value into `mul`, so copies are created and then destroyed when `mul` returns.

Comment: Right, I have no idea how I've overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
CPList* CPList :: mul (CPList p1, CPList p2) {//code}
```

When you pass by value and haven`t implemented default copy constructors - **shallow copy** of objects is created(this means that all values of members are simply copied)
 for *simple(built-in types) that is fine*),
but if you have *members in class like pointers* or references&* then their values are copied and that isn't fine because:
for example:

```
class A
{
A(){new m_pOnInt};
~A(){delete m_pOnInt};
int* m_pOnInt;
}

void someFunction(A objA);
```

when you call someFunction(objA) - temporary copy of the provided instance of A is created and pushed into stack,
after function returns control to invoker function destructors are called for all objects in stack, so ~objA() is invoked;
but you still have instance of class A which you provided as argument to the someFunction, but with non valid m_pOnInt as delete operator was applied to it, so you got a problem when destructor for instance of A is called

Solution use **"rule of 3"**: which says that when you deal with complex objects(what contain members like pointers/references - implement special member functions: **copy constructor, assignment operator, constructor**, which allows you to perform a deep copy.